# Rearrange twitter bootstrap div's to collapse to different order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three divs with class="col-md-4 col-xs-6", class="col-md-4 col-xs-12", class="col-md-4 col-xs-6" 
It collapses in one row in medium screen view:

```
    div 1 | div 2 | div 3
```

After it is resized to xs:

```
    div 1 (xs 6) 

    div 2 (xs 12) 

    div 3 (xs 6)
```

How can I anchieve this to collapse like this:

```
    div 1 (xs 6) | div 3 (xs 6) 

    div 2 (xs 12)
```

I think I could make div 3 hidden in xs view and make a copy of div 3, placing it after div 1, which becomes visible. But is there any way without dublication?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/tkgfzzx4/9/
I don't know if is possible without duplication...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out on my own how to do this. Heres my solution:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">1</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">2</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">3</div>
```

Rewrite as:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">1</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 pull-right">3</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">2</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tkgfzzx4/10/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 order-1 order-md-1">1</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 order-3 order-md-2">2</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 order-2 order-md-3 ">3</div>
```

Try this using the latest version of bootstrap.